# Is there a way to quickly paste multiple columns of data into an attribute table in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-2

So I have a shapefile with 133 rows of data, and I want to add 4 extra fields to it. My problem is that after I have created the new fields in the attribute table, I have no way to quickly paste the data for these columns from my spreadsheet. Can someone show me how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Save the spreadsheet as `.csv` (text) and open it using the CSV button in QGIS. You can then define a join in the properties tab of the shapefile. This will allow you to choose which columns to add to the shapefile. Finally you can save the shapefile using `Save As` to make the change permanent if required.

Comment: Can someone explain why we can't just copy paste values in a column. ArcMap does support this feature. It look a very simple feature to be added.

Comment: @Someone191- I'm sure the developers would be happy to accept your contribution of this simple feature.

Comment: I wish I know how to develop. One day I will :)
P.S. is there a way to contact QGIS and request this feature.

Answer (score 2):

You could just open the .dbf file in OpenOffice/LibreOffice Calc and paste it normally the data from your spreadsheet. The dbf file is in your shapefile folder.

Comment: The problem is, I have many dbf files in my folder for this shapefile, so which one do I pick?

Comment: You only have one .dbf file per shapefile. You can do this to make sure you are editing the right one. Copy the one shapefile you want to edit into an empty folder. This contains probably 4 types: .shp, .prj, .dbf and may be .shx. and they all have the same name of the shapefile.

Comment: Thanks, my mistake, I was looking at the entire folder which contained multiple layers of data.

Comment: one problem, it is currently taking a very long time to load the document into either libre office or open office, will it load eventually?

Comment: I am not sure. Make sure the quality of your data is intact. It is always easy to make some mistakes when pasting over the fields.

Comment: Can someone explain why we can't just copy paste values in a column. ArcMap does support this feature. It look a very simple feature to be added.